# Как удалить все пробелы из строки. Нужно решить через while и указатели

Tags: c, алгоритм

```
char str[80] = "gre qg1 256g#r4 6c aegev e gea, =2g +rd*gf g3t523gr"; 
char token[80];
char *p, *t;

cout << str << '\n';

p = str;    

//считываем строку.
while (*p){
    t = token;
    //считываем строку до первого пробела и копируем в строку в token
    while (*p != ' ' && *p){
        *t = *p;
        ++t; ++p;
    } 
    //если встретился пробел перемещаемся на следующюю позицию
    if (*p)
        ++p;                
    }       
cout << token << endl;
```

Comment: А в чём вопрос? Что-то не так в коде?

Comment: Да, не могу понять

Comment: А зачем еще вложенный цикл? Просто while(*p++){ if(*p != ' ')*t++ = *p;}

Comment: Не можете понять потому что как-то сложно всё наизобретали :)

Comment: сейчас попробуем

Comment: результат какой же что и был

Comment: Что-то сегодня вопросы про одно и то же :) Препод тот же, что ли?

Comment: Нет, хочу разобрать просто

Comment: Чтобы разобраться - пользуйтесь отладчиком. Без него можно долго зависать над каждой строчкой, пытаясь понять что не так.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте проговорить алгоритм. Словами, можно вслух. Написать на бумажке карандашом псевдокод и "прошагать" его:

```
пока есть символы в строке
  если символ не пробел
    скопировать по назначению
    увеличить указатель назначения
  конец если
  увеличить указатель источника
конец пока
```

И написать его на C, буквально:

```
static char * rm_spaces( char * src )
{
    char * from = src;
    char * to = src;

    while( *from )
    {
        if( *from != ' ' )
        {
            *to = *from;
            to++;
        }
        from++;
    }
    *to = 0;
    return src;
}
```

Работает? Тогда можно и оптимизировать.

Comment: Да, всё работает спс.

Comment: *to = 0; Что значит это строчка, словами можешь объяснить?

Comment: Раз возникает такой вопрос, то всё-таки лучше сначала почитать какой-нибудь учебник по C самого начального уровня... И добраться до главы про C-строки.

Answer (score 0):

```
char str[80] = "gre qg1 256g#r4 6c aegev e gea, =2g +rd*gf g3t523gr"; //строка символов
char token[80];
char *p, *t;

cout << str << '\n';

p = str;    
t = token;

while (*p){         
    if (*p != ' '){
        *t = *p;
        ++t;
    }
    ++p;
}
cout << token << '\n';
```

Вот я переделал в main-не, пока функции плохо понимаю, почему у меня в строке лишние символы?

Comment: Потому что завершающего нуля в `token` нет. Замечание про отладчик проигнорировали, да? А вот с ним бы сразу это понятно стало.

Comment: Если вы плохо понимаете функции, то сначала разберитесь в этом. Потому что если вы не знаете основ языка, вам нужно получить от преподавателя справедливую двойку, и прочитать книжку. Не надейтесь, что «так прокатит». Бездельников в программисты не берут.

Comment: причём тут преподаватель и студент?

Comment: Ну, раз по сути претензий нет, то хотя бы отсюда начать можно :) http://lib.ru/CTOTOR/starterkit.txt Лучше с самого начала и по шагам. Но если не терпится, то крутить до слов "Строки есть массивы БУКВ". Но потом всё равно вернуться на начало и по шагам.